# Cross compile error "arm-none-eabi-g++ cannot find entry symbol"

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I have a problem about cross compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

this is a simple hello world code I used.

I'm using arm-none-eabi-g++, downloaded from mentor graphics. Here is the error.
I don't know what lib is missed.

```
/home/kang/Utils/arm-2013.05/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00008018
/home/kang/Utils/arm-2013.05/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-abort.o): In function `abort':
abort.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `_exit'
/home/kang/Utils/arm-2013.05/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_kill_r':
signalr.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `_kill'
/home/kang/Utils/arm-2013.05/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_getpid_r':
signalr.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `_getpid'
/home/kang/Utils/arm-2013.05/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
/home/kang/Utils/arm-2013.05/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): In function `_write_r':
writer.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `_write'
/home/kang/Utils/arm-2013.05/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): In function `_close_r':
closer.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `_close'
/home/kang/Utils/arm-2013.05/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function `_fstat_r':
fstatr.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `_fstat'
/home/kang/Utils/arm-2013.05/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function `_isatty_r':
isattyr.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `_isatty'
/home/kang/Utils/arm-2013.05/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): In function `_lseek_r':
lseekr.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `_lseek'
/home/kang/Utils/arm-2013.05/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): In function `_read_r':
readr.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `_read'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and this is compiler version.

$ arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -v

> Using built-in specs.
>   COLLECT_GCC=/home/kang/Utils/arm-2013.05/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/kang/Utils/arm-2013.05/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/lto-wrapper
>   Target: arm-none-eabi Configured with:
>   /scratch/jbrown/2013.05-arm-eabi-release/src/gcc-4.7-2013.05/configure
>   --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-eabi --enable-threads --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-extra-sgxxlite-multilibs --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-specs='%{save-temps: -fverbose-asm} -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MAJ__=2013 -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MIN__=5 -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_REV__=23 %{O2:%{!fno-remove-local-statics: -fremove-local-statics}} %{O*:%{O|O0|O1|O2|Os:;:%{!fno-remove-local-statics:
>   -fremove-local-statics}}}' --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-shared --enable-lto --with-newlib --with-pkgversion='Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.05-23' --with-bugurl=https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/ --disable-nls --prefix=/opt/codesourcery --with-headers=yes --with-sysroot=/opt/codesourcery/arm-none-eabi --with-build-sysroot=/scratch/jbrown/2013.05-arm-eabi-release/install/arm-none-eabi
>   --with-gmp=/scratch/jbrown/2013.05-arm-eabi-release/obj/pkg-2013.05-23-arm-none-eabi/arm-2013.05-23-arm-none-eabi.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr
>   --with-mpfr=/scratch/jbrown/2013.05-arm-eabi-release/obj/pkg-2013.05-23-arm-none-eabi/arm-2013.05-23-arm-none-eabi.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr
>   --with-mpc=/scratch/jbrown/2013.05-arm-eabi-release/obj/pkg-2013.05-23-arm-none-eabi/arm-2013.05-23-arm-none-eabi.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr
>   --with-ppl=/scratch/jbrown/2013.05-arm-eabi-release/obj/pkg-2013.05-23-arm-none-eabi/arm-2013.05-23-arm-none-eabi.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr
>   --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-cloog=/scratch/jbrown/2013.05-arm-eabi-release/obj/pkg-2013.05-23-arm-none-eabi/arm-2013.05-23-arm-none-eabi.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr
>   --with-libelf=/scratch/jbrown/2013.05-arm-eabi-release/obj/pkg-2013.05-23-arm-none-eabi/arm-2013.05-23-arm-none-eabi.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr
>   --disable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-poison-system-directories --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/jbrown/2013.05-arm-eabi-release/install/arm-none-eabi/bin
>   --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/jbrown/2013.05-arm-eabi-release/install/arm-none-eabi/bin
>   Thread model: single gcc version 4.7.3 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite
>   2013.05-23)

Comment: Why are you usong a "bare-metal" toolchain? If you are using Terry Guo's gear, then you need to specify `--specs=nosys.specs`. You should also show how you are compiling/linking. It should be as simple as (assuming a toolchain with a libc): `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc mysource.c -o myprogram.exe --sysroot=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You downloaded the wrong toolchain.

`arm-linux-gnueabi-g++` is built using `arm-none-eabi`, which is used for bare metal programs. This does not contain *libc* i.e the standard libraries (glibc or eglibc) are not present in this toolchain.

So, you need to download the `arm-none-linux-gnueabi` toolchain (i.e `arm-2013.05-24-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2`, not `arm-2013.11-24-arm-none-eabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2`
).

To verify the above, type:

```
cd /home/kang/Utils/arm-2013.05/arm-none-eabi
```

Here you will find only `bin  include  lib  share`, and no `libc` directory.

Download `arm-2013.05-24-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2`; here you'll find a folder `arm-2013.05/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc`.

You can also verify by writing:

```
arm-linux-eabi-g++ -print-sysroot and 
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -print-sysroot
```

Also refer to this previous question: [how to work with external libraries when cross compiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900855/how-to-work-with-external-libraries-when-cross-compiling/18920937#18920937)

Comment: Can you clean this answer up a little?

Comment: I don't think this is correct; `arm-none-gnueabi` would be bare-metal, but with "Linux" mentioned in `arm-linux-gnueabi` it should be equivalent to `arm-none-linux-gnueabi`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit please see the specs he mentioned above

Comment: Oh, right, yes. Your answer wasn't clear on this. So he downloaded the wrong toolchain _and_ it had a very misleading file name!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit for your kind information he downloaded wrong tool-chain is not by seeing my answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you're saying.

Comment: I don't know what I do. could you tell me what I do? I'm using a arm-none-eabi- compiler. should I download arm-linux-gnueabi?

Comment: @user3203585 ya you need to download arm-2013.05-24-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2

Comment: @user3203585: We both already told you what to do, in our answers. Please read the answers. You are looking for the _GNU/Linux_ target, not _EABI_.

Answer (score 1):

> <strike>I'm using arm-linux-gnueabi-g++. it downloaded form mentor graphics.</strike>

<strike>This is misnamed. All your output suggests that Mentor Graphics have packaged a `arm-none-gnueabi` toolchain and incorrectly named it `arm-linux-gnueabi` (which doesn't even fit naming conventions).</strike>

> sorry, I mistyped my compiler. I'm using arm-none-eabi-g++

Get yourself a version of the `arm-none-linux-gnueabi` toolchain (i.e. targetting GNU/Linux rather than EABI).

This one will contain the GCC runtime which interfaces with the Linux operating system. All those functions you're missing right now are part of that interface.

Comment: @user3203585: There you go then!