# Where can I find the real arm-none-linux-gnueabi?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

Some time before I installed arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc compiler collection and compiled embedded applications for IGEP board. I have many Eclipse projects which has double build configurations (one for UBUNTU based desktop, the other for ARM based IGEPv2 board).

Now, I formatted my drive (I use Ubuntu 12.04) , I rescued my projects and what I see? "arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc" is not available? I can download it nowhere.. Instead, all the links go to another download by "Mentor Graphics", which is named "arm-none-eabi-gcc". I do not know the difference between. I setup this package and correct all my .../CodeSourcery/... type of paths to /MentorGraphics/..., but when I compile I have the following error:

> /home/fercis/MentorGraphics/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI/arm-none-eabi/include/termios.h:4:25: 
>   fatal error:   sys/termios.h: No such file or directory

Then I looked at the include file of the arm compiler collection under "/home/fercis/MentorGraphics/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI/arm-none-eabi/include" and what I see was a termios.h under the .../include directory, which only includes .../include/sys/termios.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include <sys/termios.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And, There is no "/sys/termios.h". Something must be terribly wrong! Help please?

Comment: [Here is one set](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi).  The name *arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc* by itself means nothing.  It is just a name;  You need a cross compiler for the IGEP.  Is it hard float, armv5, armv6, or armv7?  You also need to install other packages besides the compiler; like the standard library and the IGEPv2 Linux headers for whatever version is on the board. *arm-non-eabi-gcc* is generally a bare metal compiler.  You are looking at the wrong part of the mentor site, if that is where you got the compiler.

Comment: there is no "real" arm-none-linux-gnueabi.  You can download it many places.  the none-linux... can cross compile binaries that will run as linux applications for example the none-eabi is more for bare metal, depending on how you do it though you can bare metal with either.  If you are intersted in termios.h you likely want the linux one.  both are available from mentor graphics on the same web page you simply select the right one and they will send you a download link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217425/cross-compile-error-arm-none-eabi-g-can-not-find-entry-symbol/21217588#21217588 have look @ this

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own toolchain for the IGEPv2 following these steps:

Install dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install diffstat
$ sudo apt-get install texi2html
$ sudo apt-get install texinfo
$ sudo apt-get install gawk
$ sudo apt-get install chrpath
$ sudo apt-get install gnupg
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl3
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl3-gnutls
$ sudo apt-get install python-pycurl
```

Clone IGEPv2 repo:

$ git clone -b denzil git://git.isee.biz/pub/scm/poky.git

Download isee layer:

```
$ cd poky
$ git clone -b denzil git://git.isee.biz/pub/scm/meta-isee.git
```

Setup bitbake environment:

$ source oe-init-build-env

Add isee layer on conf/bblayers.conf file:

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /path/to/poky/meta \
  /path/to/poky/meta-yocto \
  /path/to/poky/meta-isee \
"
```

Change MACHINE on conf/local.conf file:

MACHINE ??= "igep00x0"

This command generates toolchain:

```
$ bitbake meta-toolchain-sdk
```

This is a good time to take a long coffee...

At the end of process, SDK will be available here:

```
build/tmp/deploy/sdk/igep-sdk-yocto-toolchain-1.2.1-2.tar.bz2
```

Install SDK in your host machine:

```
$ tar xvfz igep-sdk-yocto-toolchain-1.2.1-2.tar.bz2 -C /
```

Enjoy it! :)