# Advice regarding installing ARM toolchain on Ubuntu VM (64bit)

Tags: linux, arm, toolchain

Trying to compile Linux kernel for arm platform on a Ubuntu virtual machine

```
$make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
```

It fails as follows

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
```

Tried to install

```
$sudo apt-get install arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc

E: unable to locate package arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

Where to find the correct package? how to include it in the system? (I found a couple of links on line that didn't work for me). It would be great if you could provide a correct solution or reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Download arm-2013.05-24-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2 from https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/

   or https://sourcery.mentor.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/subscription?@template=lite

   Get  correct version of the arm-none-linux-gnueabi toolchain (i.e. targetting `GNU/Linux` rather than `EABI`).
2. untar it

   ```
   tar xvf arm-2013.05-24-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2
   ```
3. open bashrc

   ```
   vi .bashrc
   ```

   at the end add below comand

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:{path to toolchain}arm-2013.05/bin
   ```

   e.g `export PATH=$PATH:/home/vinay/under_linux/arm-2013.05/bin`

   save it and quit the terminal.

then you can cross-compile without everytime export.

Also take of correct toolchain there are two toolchain available choose according to your requirement.

[Cross compile error "arm-none-eabi-g++ cannot find entry symbol"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217425/cross-compile-error-arm-none-eabi-g-can-not-find-entry-symbol/21217588#21217588)

Comment: https://sourcery.mentor.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/subscription?@template=lite ..it isn't a opensource..right?

Comment: download lite version or u can download from linaro-toolchain its open source https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries

Answer (score 6):

The Ubuntu package names are gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf.

For building the kernel, which one you use does not make much difference. For building anything else, "gnueabihf" is the hard-float version. For any modern ARM processor (this statement excludes the Raspberry PI), this is the one you would want.

Comment: Unable to locate the pacakges mentioned above arm-linux-gnuabihf-gcc

Comment: Sorry, I keep getting confused by how they reverse the order - it's http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf.

Comment: I need to use following command to cross compile..but this doesn't works yet..make menuconfig ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-

Comment: No, you would of course need to adjust your command line to the binary names installed: arm-linux-gnueabihf- instead of arm-none-linux-gnueabi-

Comment: gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf is not enough to compile kernel for aarch64. the process will fail with the error: "linux kernel unknown type name __uint128_t"

Comment: @OlegKokorin that is correct, aarch64 is compiled using a different toolchain. You'll want  gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu.