# build kernel with aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to build the kernel source on my platform with the following command:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- generic-v8-defconfig
```

However, the error messages appear as shown in the following:

```
/bin/sh: 1: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: not found
```

It's obvious I have not this version of gcc installed on my laptop.

I then followed

http://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/main/gcc-4.8-aarch64-linux-gnu/

This to install gcc-4.8-aarch-linux-gnu,

however, I still get the same error message.

Ubuntu version: 14.04

Please let me know if you know how to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266586/advice-regarding-installing-arm-toolchain-on-ubuntu-vm-64bit/22266762#22266762

Answer (score 7, accepted):

looks like a PATH issue. what happens when you just type "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc "in your shell? does it find the compiler?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue has been fixed.

Comment: @Sam could you let us know how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266586/advice-regarding-installing-arm-toolchain-on-ubuntu-vm-64bit/22266762#22266762

Answer (score 27):

Maybe aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc is not installed. Try

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: `# pacman -S aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` on arch linux

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linaro-maintainers/toolchain
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-**version**-aarch64-linux-gnu
```

Make sure to replace `**version**` by the correct version.

Answer (score 2):

Use ndk tool to install the arm64 cross compiler:

`$NDK_ROOT/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --arch=arm64 --install-dir=/opt/android-toolchain
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-toolchain`

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

debian/ubuntu:

```sh
sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu # GNU C compiler for the arm64 architecture
sudo apt-get install g++-aarch64-linux-gnu # GNU C++ compiler
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this, it will get solved
CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- make flash.bin -j $(nproc --all)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).