# install cross compiler to build custom kernel for qemu

Tags: kernel, cross-compiling, qemu

I'm trying run ubuntu snappy core on qemu. To do that i need kernel for snappy core. I found a description how to do that here : [custom linux kernel for snappy core](https://electronicsconcepts.wordpress.com/2015/05/28/running-ubuntu-snappy-on-qemu/)

They said that i need a cross compiler so i follow [install cross compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266586/advice-regarding-installing-arm-toolchain-on-ubuntu-vm-64bit) description to install arm-none-linux-gnu-gcc but i can't dowload cross compiler at the link they provide so I follow this link to download cross compiler:  download.opencontroller.com/tools/arm-2013.05-24-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2

Then i follow the decription in [install cross compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266586/advice-regarding-installing-arm-toolchain-on-ubuntu-vm-64bit) to install cross compiler. But when i use command: "**make ARCH=arm**" to buid kernel i recieve error: **make: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found**
There are some people have this error too and they said that it's because they are using 64bit version which is not my case (I'm using ubuntu 32bit version)
.Can some one help me out ?

here is the line that i append to .bashrc file:**export PATH=$PATH:/home/thanh/draft/arm-2013.05/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin**
All my .bashrc file here: drive.google.com/file/d/0By0_QpVISV27Z0pZTUIwN3FKMWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: why no one answer me ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please bear in mind that questions on this site are answered by volunteers; there is no SLA and you are not entitled to an immediate response.  Plus today is New Year's Day in the Julian calendar, which is a public holiday in many jurisdictions.

Comment: So simple command `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` works in your environment (that is, it fails, but with reason other than `Command not found`)? You may try to set `CROSS_COMPILE` variable to `/home/thanh/draft/arm-2013.05/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev can you explain more clearly ? i don't understand what you mean. How can i set cross_compile variable to /home/thanh/draft/arm-2013.05/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi‌​- ?

Comment: Like you pass variable `ARCH` to make, you may pass other variables: `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=<value>`.

Comment: i have made it now. Thank you :)