# Raspberrypi cross compile error

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to cross compile a cpp application for my Raspberrypi board from my virtual Ubuntu machine. I first installed the required development tools like this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf
sudo apt-get install gdb-multiarch
```

Afterward I created the following hello world application:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Hello Worl from Pi" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled the program like this:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ hello.cpp hello
```

When I execute the binary I get in the console the output "Speicherzugriffsfehler" which is German and means something like "memory access problem".

What might be the problem?

Comment: Speicherzugriffsfehler == segmentation fault

Comment: It sounds worse in german.

Comment: Add a [`--sysroot`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18920937/608639) to tell the toolchain where to find the ARM headers and libraries. You might even need `-mfpu=hard` (it depends on [`arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -dumpmachine`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11727855/608639)). Or easier, SSH into your RPI and just do a native compile.